# using egrep in perl and travel through the directories

Tags: perl, unix

I have a directory and inside that directory i have x sub directories and inside each sub directory i have many files and folders , here i need to grep for a specific keyword say "XYZ" and put the results in text file with the full path.

How can i open each files under sub directory(i do not know the filename since i clone from git) and search for specific keyword.

And below is the snapshot of my code 
i use egrep command , but here i am not getting the full path(the full path should be (/dir/sub/file/)

since i am new to coding i need some input. thank you

```
$path1="/nfs/pais/abh/pgm4.txt";

foreach my $file ( glob('/nfs/abc/*') )

{
        if(-d $file){
        chdir ("$file") or die "cannot change";
    print(cwd); my $cmd = "egrep -nre 'Non' *.*  ";
    `egrep -nre 'nemu' *.* >> $path1` ;
    `egrep -nre 'ELATION' *.* >> $path1` ;
    `egrep -nre 'EULATION' *.* >> $path1` ;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run egrep multiple times...you could just do it with one egrep or even better do it in a couple of lines of Perl.

You just need to `open` the file using the full path, and then for each line in the file (read in using `<$fh>`) you can use a regular expression to find lines that match and `print` them to your output file.

```
open(my $output,">","/nfs/pais/abh/pgm4.txt") || die;

if(open(my $fh,"<","/net/abc/$file"))
  {
  while(<$fh>)
    {
    if( /Nonemu|EMULATION|INTEL_EMULATION/)
      {
      print $output $_;
      }
    }
  close($fh);
  }
```

Also it's not a good idea to use `chdir` like that as it firstly assumes you're in the right starting directory, but it also doesn't "undo" the directory change, so will fail to work on the next subdirectory.

If you want to traverse multiple layers of subdirectories, you'll need to write a recursive sub(routine).

Answer (score 2):

With your `perl` script you are not using `perl`'s pattern matching capabilities. It would be possible to program everything in `perl` without using `egrep`.

But I think it is easier to use `find` in combination with `egrep`.

```
find /nfs/abc -type f -exec egrep -ne 'XYZ' {} /dev/null \;
```

Comment: `find /nfs/abc -type f -exec egrep -Hne 'XYZ' {} +` may be a preferable version of that solution.  Most of the time, the difference is insignificant, but if the directories are large, it could provide a significant performance improvement (it invokes egrep on groups of files, so it does a lot fewer fork/execs, and prints the filename even if there's just one file on the command line.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a perl tag here, I thought I'd give a perl answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub file_check {
    open my $FH, '<', $_ or return;
    while (<$FH>) {
        if (/Non|nemu|EU?LATION/) {
            print "$File::Find::name: $_";
        }
    }
    close $FH;
}

my $path1 = "/nfs/pais/abh/pgm4.txt";
open my $OUT, '>', $path1
or die "$0: cannot write to $path1: $!\n";

File::Find::find(\&file_check </nfs/abc/*>);
```

This is, admittedly, silent on change directory failures, rather than giving a fatal error with no context.  File::Find doesn't actually provide a hook to do that, or even to provide the warnings that the unix find command would give.